# Finding a downward sloping function given a tangent point on a linear curve

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, derivatives, slope

I have a linear function $10-5x$. I am trying to create a downward sloping curve at a point where the tangency point is $(1.5, 2.5)$.

I tried using a function of $3.75/x$, but instead of making it a tangent to the linear curve it instead intersects it. How do I make a function that is tangent to the linear curve at point $(1.5,2.5)$?

Answer (score 2):

Lets continue with what you had in mind. You wanted to fit a hyperbola to be the tangent to the line. You need at the point x=1.5 to have gradient -5 and you also need for (1.5,2.5) to be a solution. We begin with 5*(1.5)^2/x to get the gradient that you want of -5 at the point x=1.5. We can then adjust this function on the y-axis by adding or subtracting some amount to make it a tangent. The final curve of y = 11.25/x-5 fits what you wanted.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] your answer to use mathjax for math: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you so much this is definitely what I am looking for. I think I get the hang of the step to make a formula. Can you please share your steps and reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let try with a parabola $y=ax^2+bx+c$ with the conditions

- passing through the point $(1.5,2.5)$: $2.5=a(1.5)^2+b(1.5)+c$
- same tangent at the point $(1.5,2.5)$: $-5=2a(1.5)+b$
- open upward: $a>0$ (free parameter)

Comment: Sorry I dont follow, I should find the values of a,b, and c that satisfy the equations?

Comment: Yes of course with $a$ negative and free, we can set for example $a=-1$ or $a=-2$. For any negative value for $a$ we can find a parabola tangent to that point. Here a [possible solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+10-5x%2C+-2x%5E2%2Bx%2B5.5) (case $a=-2$). Let try to find the case $a=-1$ by yourself!

Comment: I see, however, in my case I have to find a convex shaped parabola, can you please provide another example?

Comment: @Andrew Do you mean open upward? In this case it suffices to take any $a>0$. For exampe here is a [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+10-5x%2C+x%5E2-8x%2B12.25) for $a=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that the tangent line at $P(1.5,2.5)$ has equation $y=10-5x$ gives you two conditions about a function $f$:

1. $P$ is on the graph of $f$, that is $f(1.5)=2.5$
2. The tangent at $P$ has slope $-5$, that is $f'(1.5)=-5$.

You tried a function of the form $f(x)=\frac{a}{x}$. There is only one parameter so it was unlikely to lead to a solution.

Try functions with two or more parameters: $f(x)=\frac{a}{x}+b$, $f(x)=\frac{a}{x+b}$, etc.